# tree contextMenu disappears immediately

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm using a tree with a contextMenu here's the code :

```
      <p:contextMenu id="campaignPlaneTreeContextMenu" for="campaignPlanetree" >
          <p:menuitem value="New Camapign" disabled="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.campaignOptionsFlag}" />
          <p:menuitem value="Assign" disabled="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.FSTOptions}" />
          <p:menuitem value="Copy campaign" disabled="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.FSTOptions}"/>
          <p:menuitem value="Paste Campaign" disabled="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.pasteOptionCampaignFlag}"/>
          <p:menuitem value="Delete" disabled="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.FSTOptions}" />
          <p:menuitem value="Import Tests" disabled="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.campaignOptionsFlag}" />
      </p:contextMenu>
      <p:tree id="campaignPlanetree"
                    value="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.root}" var="node"
                    selectionMode="single"
                    selection="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.selectedNode}"
                     dynamic="true">

          <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.onCampaignPlaneNodeSelect}" update=":campaignForm:addCampaignBtn :campaignForm:renameCampaignBtn :campaignForm:importCampaignBtn :campaignForm:deleteCampaignBtn :campaignForm:importCampaignDlg :campaignForm:campaignPlaneTreeContextMenu" /> 

          <p:treeNode  value="#{node}">
              <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
          </p:treeNode>
           .....
```

ManagedBean:

```
if(selectedNode.getData() instanceof Campaign){// when a user select a tree node the contextmenu item are disabled and enabled

          setCampaignOptionsFlag(false);
        ....   
  }
```

Without the disabled attribute every thing is good, but after adding it the contextmenu disappears immediately.

Comment: @akoskm no , sorry i didn't have attention

Comment: Same for me, I think its a bug in latest primefaces version. You should file an issue.

Comment: @djmj have look at Amira Manai answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that when you put the cursor on the arrow of each node i mean in the left of the selected tree node the context menu doesn't disappear immediatly .

But in the last tree level (the leafs) you wont see the arrow because the node is not expandble 
So it's surely a primefaces  bug